# How to Identify all odd numbers divisible by 5 upto number 40, and save in a list

Tags: python-3.x

How to write the codes to Identify all odd numbers divisible by 5 upto number 40, and save in a list in python

Comment: please try some own code in python

Comment: Sorry, we don't write code. We help you correct your code.

Comment: Please try to conform to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

```py
listOfInts = []
for i in range(1,41):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        if i % 5 == 0:
            listOfInts.append(i)
```

First line makes an empty line. Second line makes it do the function on every number 1-40, third line checks if it odd, fourth line checks if it is divisible by 5. If it passes all those, it gets added to the list.

Comment: Yeah I had accidentally created a tuple. I saw the problem after I asked

Answer (score 0):

```
Odds = []

for i in range(1,41):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        if i % 5 == 0:
            Odds.append(i)
print(Odds)
```

outputs:

```
[5, 15, 25, 35]
```

Comment: Just to note - you can use `range(1, 41, 2)` here to skip over even numbers so you don't need the odd/even check... in fact, the entire thing could become a fairly simple list-comp - eg: `odds = [n for n in range(1, 41, 2) if n % 5 == 0]`...

Comment: Of course of how 5's and evens work... it literally boils down to `odds = list(range(5, 41, 10))...

Comment: @hamed nope... just pointing out other (more Pythonic ways) of achieving the same result.